# In the output shown in undefined + string how can i remove this

Tags: javascript

```js
function reverse_string() {
  var text = document.getElementById("string_reverse").value;
  var split_string = text.split(" ");
  var output = "";
  var output2 = "";

  function isEven(split_string) {
    if (split_string.length % 2 == 0)
      return output;
    else
      return output2;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < split_string.length; i += 2) {
    output += " " + split_string[i + 1] + " " + split_string[i];
    document.getElementById("reverse").innerHTML = output;
  }

  output2 += " " + output + " " + split_string[split_string.length - 1];
  document.getElementById("reverse").innerHTML = output2;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">Input Any string :
    <input type="text" style="width:250px" name="STRAT_TIME" id="string_reverse" placeholder="ex: w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <INPUT NAME="check" TYPE=Button VALUE="string reverse" onClick="reverse_string(); return false;">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="reverse" class="row">
</div>
```

Output shown: `undefined + string`.

How can i remove this?

I like it if input is 1 2 3 4 then o/t is 2 1 4 3

and another condition is if string is odd

ex 1 2 3 4 5 then needed 2 1 4 3 5

Comment: please provide a fiddle..

Comment: `split_string[i + 1]` is undefined when `i == split_string.length - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (var i = split_string.length-1; i >= 0; i --) {

    output += " " + split_string[i ] + " ";
}
document.getElementById("reverse").innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: I like it if input is 1 2 3 4    then o/t is 2 1 4 3

Comment: and another condition is if string is odd

Comment: ex 1 2 3 4 5  then needed 2 1 4 3 5

Comment: @jerin Reverse of 1 2 3 4 is  4 3 2 1

Answer (score 0):

That is because, you are splitting using `" "` and using `split_string[i + 1]`.

If I enter "Hello World! Foo."

split_string will be like

```
0: Hello
1: World!
2: Foo.
```

First Iteration will work fine. Then you increment as `i+=2`, so now `i` is `2` and `split_string[i + 1]` will be `split_string[3]` i.e. undefined.

Same will happen if you do not enter value with any `spaces`.

You can try something like this:

```js
function reverse_string() {
  var text = document.getElementById("string_reverse").value;
  var split_string = text.split(" ");
  var _temp = [];
  var len = split_string.length;
  
  console.log(len, split_string)
  
  for(var i=0; i<len/2; i++){
     _temp.push(split_string[(i*2) + 1]);
    _temp.push(split_string[(i*2)]);
  }
  console.log(_temp);
  
  document.getElementById("reverse").innerHTML = _temp.join(" ");
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">Input Any string :
    <input type="text" style="width:250px" name="STRAT_TIME" id="string_reverse" placeholder="ex: w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <INPUT NAME="check" TYPE=Button VALUE="string reverse" onClick="reverse_string(); return false;">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="reverse" class="row">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function reverse_string() {
  var text = document.getElementById("string_reverse").value;
  var split_string = text.split(" ");
  var output = "";
  var output2 = "";

  function isEven(split_string) {
    if (split_string.length % 2 == 0)
      return output;
    else
      return output2;
  }

  for (var i = split_string.length-1; i >= 0; i --) {

output += " " + split_string[i ] + " ";
}
 document.getElementById("reverse").innerHTML = output;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">Input Any string :
    <input type="text" style="width:250px" name="STRAT_TIME" id="string_reverse" placeholder="ex: w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <INPUT NAME="check" TYPE=Button VALUE="string reverse" onClick="reverse_string(); return false;">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="reverse" class="row">
</div>
```

Comment: I like it if input is 1 2 3 4 then o/t is 2 1 4 3

and another condition is if string is odd

ex 1 2 3 4 5 then needed 2 1 4 3 5

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method...

```
var str = "1234567";
var newstr = "";
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (i == 0 || i % 2 === 0) {
    var j =i+1;
    if(typeof str[j] === "undefined"){
    newstr = newstr + str[i];
    }else{
    newstr = newstr + str[i + 1] + str[i];
    }
  } 
}
```

Hope this help you...

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/next2u/w89xuen7/)

Comment: its very simple..Thank you